# batch - simple one key stroke option

Tags: batch-file

I want to make batch file, so I can do a silent install of an application

I want to give the user that executes the batch file an option
If they hit 'Spacebar' the installation continues, if they hit any other key strokes the operation aborts.

Comment: Under windows, use `pause`, under unix, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/134437/press-space-to-continue

Comment: @RC. Will pause return a different errorlevel based on which key has been pressed?

Comment: I don't know, and I don't have a windows system at my disposal

Comment: I'm quite sure that `pause` does not modify the `ErrorLevel` at all...

Comment: That is why I asked. It would not help, because it could not be determined if the spacebar has been hit or another key...

Comment: if the use of the spacebar is an important matter then read the new post

Answer (score 3):

Here is robust, but non-intuitive method using REPLACE.

```
@echo off
setlocal

echo Press [Space] to continue, any other key to abort...
set "space="
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%A in ('replace.exe ? . /u /w') do if "%%A" equ " " set "space=1"
if defined space (
  echo CONTINUE
) else (
  echo ABORT
)
```

The replace command in the above code is guaranteed to have no effect, yet it still prompts the user to press a key, and the key is echoed to stdout in a way that can be captured by FOR /F. I first saw this technique at [Password Input (new method)](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6382).

Using the REPLACE technique, I have developed a routine that can recognize and store key presses for all single byte characters from 0x00 through 0xFF at:
[Read key presses via REPLACE - New functions :getKey, :getAnyKey, :getMaskedInput](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7396)

Answer (score 2):

As a proof of concept, this read any keystroke (no arrows nor special keys) and perform action if it was the *spacebar*

```
@echo off

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set/a abort=1
<NUL set/p="Hit space to continue, any oyher to abort "

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('xcopy /w "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>nul') do (if not defined key set "key=%%A") & set "key=!key:~-1!" & (if "!key!" equ " " set/a abort=0)

if %abort% equ 1 (
  echo(&echo(&echo(* You have not pressed the spacebar key. Aborting... [your key: %key%]
) else (
  echo(&echo(&echo(* You have pressed the spacebar key. Have a nice day...
)  
EndLocal
exit/B
```

Answer (score 0):

For the determination of a space bar it is quite heavy, but you can use `choice` to let them choose between single buttons.

Use it like this:

```
choice /c:AB /m "Abort ->A; Continue ->B"
Goto:choice%errorlevel%
:choice1
REM Choice A
:choice2
REM Choice B
```

The command sets the intern variable `errorlevel` to the number of the chosen option. You can set different keys in the /c switch and set a message with /m.

I am not sure if there is an option for a space bar though.
Btw: Other keys will simply be ignored.